# BroadcastReceiver crash when updating location

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to get the location information, but when I broadcast, the program crashes. I debugged it but couldn't solve it, any ideas? What is causing the error?

UpdateLocation.java

```
public class UpdateLocation extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION"/>
```

Crash log

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myapplication, PID: 4786
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.example.myapplication.test flg=0x400010 } in com.example.myapplication.UpdateLocation@f8eae4d
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1676)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.
        at androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation(InstrumentationRegistry.java:45)
        at androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(ApplicationProvider.java:41)
        at com.example.myapplication.UpdateLocation.onReceive(UpdateLocation.java:35)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.lambda$getRunnable$0$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args(LoadedApk.java:1666)
        at android.app.-$$Lambda$LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args$_BumDX2UKsnxLVrE6UJsJZkotuA.run(Unknown Source:2)
```

Comment: It feels like you are trying to run this in a unit test (`test/`) instead of an instrumented test (`androidTest/`).

Comment: @CommonsWare When i say `test`, I mean an `example`.I apologize for the random naming.

Comment: Have you tried to use - context.getSystemService ? Instead of ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext.

Comment: No, I was referring to `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No instrumentation registered! Must run under a registering instrumentation.` from your stack trace. That feels like you are trying to run this code inside of a unit test inside of an instrumented test.

Comment: can you add the  repository  link ?

Comment: @AnujSharma No it still crashes, location returns null

Comment: @AlejandroGonzalez  Here you can see all my code 
https://0bin.net/paste/GOd51NfW#dO6Fvb4JFIzzNK6Ehkm+i5YMT-cPdEk0keaR6eXQuZZ

Comment: @coret92697 What is the  variable LOCATION_SERVICE  value?